# Django ccbv.co.uk

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Is there something simillar to https://ccbv.co.uk site which is offline now? There was descriptions of all class and methods, with source code, in django class-based view on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The site seems to be online. https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ccbv.co.uk.html

If you can't reach the site somehow, you can always check the views directly from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/contrib/auth/views.py). The repo is commented pretty nicely. Other than that, the original documentation has a [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/) that explains the views in detail.